# Collapsing only one item of an array of items deployed through a Ng-For in Angular using data-toggle and data-target

Tags: angular, ngfor

how could i specifically collapse a item of my selected card of an array of cards in angular.
In this app im doing there is a point where in i bring all the data gathered by cards with its respective information,and in the cards design i include a collapsable feature .The point is that i expose all that data using an ngfor , looping over the database replying the information requested.
But when i request the collpase for one card the other ones also collapse .

```
component that bring all the cards 
        <mat-card>

       <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4" *ngFor="let post of allPortafolio;let i=index">//FOR LOOP BRINGING ALL CARDS
         .......some code 

         <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

            <h4 *ngIf="post.allComments">
              <small><strong>Comments</strong>({{post.allComments.length>0?post.allComments.length:"No comments"}})</small>
            </h4>

            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down fa-2x" *ngIf="up" (click)="up=!up"  aria-hidden="true" role="button" data-toggle="collapse"
              data-target="#commentOverflow1"> </i>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-up fa-2x"*ngIf="!up" (click)="up=!up" aria-hidden="true" role="button" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#commentOverflow1" > </i>//THESE TWO ICONS COLLAPSE UP AND DOWN THE NEXT CONTAINER

            <div class="container"  >
              <div *ngFor="let comment of post.allComments; let ind = index" id="commentOverflow1" class="collapse">
                <small><strong>Published by: {{comment.name}}</strong></small>
                <h6>{{comment.comments}}</h6>
              </div>
            </div>//THIS CONTAINER HAS ALL THE CARDS AFTER NGFOR FUCNTION

          </div>
        </div>
      </mat-card>
</div>
```

But as i explained having in main the data-toggle aims a specific id and eventually this ngfor brings
all data gathered in cards with same id , any time i click the collapser icons , all cards collapse down or up, instead of only that one i oreder collpase to

[image]

Comment: You need to add a new field `up` to each `comment` in `post.allComments` array. Then you can use `comment.up` to replace your current `up`.

Comment: Are you iterating (ngFor) to render more than one card?

Comment: Yes the ngfor renders an array of object whom i build the cards from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@EnriqueGF, when you say `component that bring all the cards`  do you mean that you has some like

```
<div *ngFor="let post of AllPost;let i=index">
   <app-card [post]="post">...</app-card>
</div>
```

?

If the response is true, must be work: up is a variable of the component and it's uniq for each component

But if you has no component, else

```
<div *ngFor="let post of AllPost;let i=index">
   <mat-card>
     ...
   </mat-card>
</div>
```

you need convert your variable `up` in an array. that's declare an array of variables up

```
up:boolean[]=[]
```

And replace yours `up` by `up[i]`

```
  <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down fa-2x" *ngIf="up[i]" (click)="up[i]=!up[i]"..> 
  <i class="fa fa-angle-double-up fa-2x" *ngIf="!up[i]" (click)="up[i]=!up[i]"..> 
  <div  *ngIf="up[i]" class="container"  >
     ...
  </div>
```

You has differents cards, you need diferents variables (or an array)

Comment: isn't working for me , i declared up as a boolean with value equal true , now been changed to your explanation keeps the same behavior .I edit my question

Comment: Sorry Sorry ....it does work perfect!!!!...Thanks @Eliseo!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies here:

```
id="commentOverflow1"
```

You create multiple cards with same id:

```
data-target="#commentOverflow1"
```

Your way to fix this is to create dynamic id:

```
[data-target]="'#' + 'commentOverflow' + cardIndex"
```

And in your comment element also:

```
[id]="'commentOverflow' + cardIndex"
```

One last thing, you need to wrap your comments with one collapsible container. Right now you created multiple comments with ngFor, and make them collapsible, each one of them...

Comment: sorry but the post index , can't understand its paper here...having in mind the collapser button are outside the ngfor , can't use that post index

Comment: Sorry but didn't work, could you explain on more detail Asaf?.Thanks!!

Comment: You create multiple cards, so you need to concat the card index to the `id` to make it unique.

Comment: Also, I've edit my answer to be more clear about what you try to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time in reply @Asaf, also tested yours and also worked!!!!

Comment: Great, happy to help!